# How to parse calendar file dates with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, calendar, icalendar

We need to use JavaScript on the browser to read and parse calendar files (.ics)  (also called iCal formats). I wrote a custom function to read these values and then use the JavaScript Date() function to make a data object.

Is any easier and better way to do this?  Please look at my function (below), your comments would be welcome.

A typical date value from an .ics file looks like this:

DTSTART:20110914T184000Z

Need to break it apart at the colon, so:

```
var strData = 'DTSTART:20110914T184000Z'
var x = strData.indexOf(":");
var strVal = strData.slice(x + 1 );
```

next, call a function that returns a date object:

```
var dateObj = calenDate(strVal);
```

//resulting dateObj value:  Fri Oct 14 2011 18:40:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Here is the function that parses the date.

```
function calenDate(icalStr)  {
    // icalStr = '20110914T184000Z'             
    var strYear = icalStr.substr(0,4);
    var strMonth = icalStr.substr(4,2);
    var strDay = icalStr.substr(6,2);
    var strHour = icalStr.substr(9,2);
    var strMin = icalStr.substr(11,2);
    var strSec = icalStr.substr(13,2);

    var oDate =  new Date(strYear,strMonth, strDay, strHour, strMin, strSec)

return oDate;
}
```

I think something is wrong since it is getting the month wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some odd reason the month parameter is zero-based ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)).

Change this line in your function.

```
var strMonth = icalStr.substr(4,2);
```

to this:

```
var strMonth = parseInt(icalStr.substr(4,2),10)-1;
```

See working demo on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cTkTQ/

Comment: The months are zero-based?  Thanks for pointing that out!  I didn't see it in the RFC 5545.

Comment: Sorry for commenting this zombie comment, but I just want to point out that it's not months in iCal (RFC 5545) that is zero-based, but javascript Date months.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat more robust way of parsing the dates would be:

```
    var parser = XRegExp("^ (?<prefix> [^:;]+       )    # DTSTART/DTEND/DTSTAMP \n\
                            ((:|;TZID=(?<tz>[^:]+):))    # timezone \n\
                            (?<year>   [0-9]{4}     )    # year    \n\
                            (?<month>  [0-9]{2}     )    # month   \n\
                            (?<day>    [0-9]{2}     ) T  # day     \n\
                            (?<hour>   [0-9]{2}     )    # hour    \n\
                            (?<minute> [0-9]{2}     )    # minute  \n\
                            (?<second> [0-9]{2}     )    # second  \n\
                            (?<utc>     Z?          )    # utc", "x");

     parts = parser.exec (d);

     var od = new Date (parseInt (parts.year, 10),
                        parseInt (parts.month, 10) - 1,
                        parseInt (parts.day, 10),
                        parseInt (parts.hour, 10),
                        parseInt (parts.minute, 10),
                        parseInt (parts.second, 10));
```

This requires you to add an additional (tiny) dependency, [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/), which might be a bit overkill depending on your further needs, but it allows for a clean, easy to read regexp parsing of the date format in .ics files. This also takes into account the time zone identifier, if the date is not UTC. I leave it to you to add proper handling of time zones as well as the use of the `prefix` part.

The short answer (as noted by jessegavin) however, is that the `month`-parameter of the constructor expects a number between 0-11 (refer [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more information). However, `parseInt()` tries to parse leading zeros as `radix 8` (octal), so you should make sure to add `radix 10` too, that would be the second parameter to `parseInt(string [, radix])`.

Comment: Nice, didn't need to make all those variables, just goes straight into the Date constructor

Answer (score 2):

This is a new package (with tests) that seems to work well: [ical-date-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ical-date-parser)

#### Usage

```
import iCalDateParser from 'ical-date-parser';

iCalDateParser('20140422T233000Z');
```

Answer (score 0):

Сomplete solution:

```
function parseICalDate(date) {
    const year = date.substr(0, 4);
    const month = parseInt(date.substr(4, 2), 10) - 1;
    const day = date.substr(6, 2);
    const hour = date.substr(9, 2);
    const minute = date.substr(11, 2);
    const second = date.substr(13, 2);
    return new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second));
}
```