# Android Calendar Syncing

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, calendar, synchronization

I have a calendar made in jQuery. I have deployed it on web. I need to sync the calendar events with the Android Mobile Calendar. Is there any way that this can be done? And tutorials are welcome.

Thanks,
Ankit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a web app to sync with the local calendar since you don't have access to android intents and such. But you can sync events with the Google Calendar associated with the user's phone and android will automatically sync these events with it's local calendar.

See Google Calendar API's here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Update:

If you are getting an ical file from your app, Then you'll have to parse the iCal file and get the events data from it and then use the Google Calendar API to import these events into it.

See how to parse ical files in js here:

[How to parse calendar file dates with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657958/how-to-parse-calendar-file-dates-with-javascript)

you can also try this library:

https://github.com/thybag/JavaScript-Ical-Parser

Comment: I am now getting an iCal file from my app... can this be synced with the Google Calendar?